# Plotly (via R): Increase width of tooltips/hover boxes

Tags: r, plotly

I use `library(plotly)` to draw a colored interactive bar chart in R. When the user hovers a bar with the mouse, little tooltips pop up and provide information about the name of the respective color group. How can I make this tooltip wider so that it can be used with longer names?

```
library(tibble)
library(plotly)

tibble(x   = 1,
       nam = paste('reasonably long name', LETTERS),
       y   = 1:26) %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~x, y = ~y, color = ~nam, type = 'bar', hoverinfo = 'name') %>%
  layout(showlegend = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is controllable via the `layout.hoverlabel.namelength` attribute. You can set it to any integer number of characters you wish. The default is 15. To display all characters regardless of the length set it to -1.

Using your example:

```
library(tibble)
library(plotly)

tibble(x   = 1,
       nam = paste('reasonably long name', LETTERS),
       y   = 1:26) %>%
    plot_ly(x = ~x, y = ~y, color = ~nam, type = 'bar', hoverinfo = 'name') %>%
    layout(showlegend = FALSE, hoverlabel = list(namelength = -1))
```

Reference: https://plotly.com/r/reference/#scatter-hoverlabel-namelength